# Change Placeholder value of input type month

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a payment form where user can enter credit/debit card details.
For that I need user to select month and year of expiry of card.
The placeholder of the input date box should show something like this MM/YYYY or MM/YY

```html
<div class="custom-month-input">
    <label for="expiry-date" class="month-placeholder">Expiry(MM/YY)</label>
    <input type="month" id="expiry-date" name="expiry-date">
</div>
```

I tried mentioning placeholder in input box and giving it a value, but it didn't work

Comment: On my system, it doesn't ask for MM/YY, it asks for the whole name of the month and the whole year. If you want custom formatting/input, you're better off using a mask JavaScript plugin or two number fields.

Comment: Dont make it an input, it has to be a Select/option. You need to make the list up of dates within the date range you want people to choose.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="month" id="expiry-date" name="expiry-date" placeholder = "">
```

Does this work? I've added `placeholder = ""` in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using the `input type="month"` syntax, I found this:

```
<label for="start">Start month:</label>

<input type="month" id="start" name="start" min="2018-03" value="2018-05" />
```

Code snippet from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month

This lets the user fill in a number for the date and year, but it's not entirely intuitive that this is a field in which the user can type numbers.
It doesn't seem to support a placeholder value, but you can use a default value as an example